# Preventing simultaneous calls to a WCF function

Tags: c#, wcf, parallel-processing, locking, task

I have a WCF service running as a windows service. This service references a DLL containing a class X with a public method func1. func1 calls another method func2(private) asynchronously using tasks(TPL). func2 performs a long running task independently. The setup is :

### WCF

```
public string wcfFunc()
{
    X obj = new X();
    return obj.func1();
}
```

### DLL

```
public class X
    {
        static bool flag;
        public X()
        {
            flag = true;
        }   
        public string func1()
        {
            if (!flag)
                return "Already in action";

            Task t = null;
            t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func2(),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);    
            return "started";       
        }   
        void func2()
        {
            try
            {
                flag = false;
                //Does a long running database processing work through .Net code
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
}
```

The WCF function is called from a website. The website is used by multiple users. No two execution of the database processing func2 is allowed. Any user can trigger it. But during an execution, if any other user attempts to trigger it, it should show that the processing is already running.
I tried to use a static variable 'flag' to check it, but it does not seem to be working.

Any solutions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx), to prevent multiple calls to the WCF service method, you will need to first ensure that only one instances of your service can be created in addition to setting the concurrency mode.

In short, Make the following changes to your ServiceBehavior:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single,  InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class YourService: IYourService
{...}
```

**NOTE** : This will disable concurrency in all the methods exposed by your service, If you do not want that you will have to move the needed method to a separate service and then configure it as above.

Comment: Is there no other way to get only one method to have the behavior? Since I have many other methods in the service and those can (and needed to) be used simultaneously. Why is static field solution not working? Do you know of any locking solutions that can help? I tried searching but could not figure out.